# Turning on anti-aliasing in SWT

Tags: eclipse, swt, draw2d

I've called `gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);` and it does nothing. According to that method, it should work.

The Javadoc states:

> Sets the receiver's anti-aliasing
>   value to the parameter, which must be
>   one of SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.OFF or SWT.ON.

It's not working for me, and I'm painting on a simple Canvas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following worked for me in an app I built and my guesses at when/how you have to do this.

So I created a new GC, set the Antialias as you did and then drew what I needed to with that gc object.  The key is attaching it to the shell you will draw in.

```
GC gc = new GC(shell);
gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON); 
//then I attach to LightweightSystem for testing.
LightweightSystem lws = new LightweightSystem(shell);
```

Other than that make sure you do this before you draw anything.  If you have to call it afterwards maybe try calling a repaint or redraw of the entire space.

Sorry without more information I am not sure exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you're drawing labels, make sure you use `gc.setTextAntialias( SWT.ON );`

You can also check if `gc.getAdvanced()` returns true, it should after `setAntialias()` or `setTextAntialias` was set.

Besides from that it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

Following derBiggi's answer, you ca also force the advanced option to true.

```
gc.setAdvanced(true)
```